# Got java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000 In Android 6.0 only

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, mediametadataretriever

There is too many question in StackOverflow about this question but Can't get any solution about Android 6.0.

I got this Exception **only in Android 6.0**,

I tested application in Moto X Play.

In all other Android my app works completely.

I got this exception while choose Image or Video from gallery.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever dataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
dataRetriever.setDataSource(PATH);
```

**Got exception at dataRetriever.setDataSource(PATH);**

**PATH** is my image or video path like :

/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20151222-WA0003.jpg

- Added All required permission.

Comment: I think you can get something from here---> https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.java

Comment: i guess `WhatsApp Images/IMG-20151222-WA0003.jpg` creates problem

Comment: *"Added all the required permissions"* **In Android 6.0** It is requried that you ask for them at runtime, not just in the AndroidManifest any more http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html an example: https://androidhub.intel.com/posts/blundell/You_have_permission_to.html

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya No because It gives me error all time if path is anything,like camera,screenshot, picture, images etc...

Comment: @Blundell I gave all permission in my android mobile >App info> manage permissions > http://imgur.com/D31zNo9 . Still I need manage permission at run time?

Comment: @ChiragSavsani  is this issue resolved , i facing same problem for  samung g5 prime(android 8) but works fine with android 7,9,10.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation, [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) "provides a unified interface for retrieving frame and meta data from an input media file". I don't think it supports metadata retrieval from images.